# Converted Android app for Blackberry, facebook,twitter integration

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I'm new on Blackberry , 
i Converted my Android app to Blackberry. All components work normally but facebook,twitter and gmail integration don't work. I used  `"Intent.ACTION_SEND"` like

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

etc:  `"com.google.android.gm"`  package name for gmail.

Simple my question ;
Can i access any BB application via converted Android app for BB or 
How can i integrate facebook,twitter for my blackberry app, is there any solution?

Comment: Are you using the latest 10.2.1 OS to test with.  I believe that with that level, Intents are converted correctly to invocations of the native BB apps, like Facebook.

Comment: i tested it for latest version , it doesn't work. I decide to use   Facebook and Twitter libs.